# regular expression to find HTML Comment ( <!-- some string --> )

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, pcre

I use this regexp to find and replace an HTML comment traditionally:

```
//remove HTML comments
$HTML = preg_replace('/<!--(.|\s)+?-->/','',$HTML);
```

However, on one server that's apparently crashing (works fine on my VM but it's pretty high powered).

The logic is, start the comment, any character or whitespace (at least some = +), and the `?` means "don't be greedy and stop at the first --> you get"

Is there a better way to write this, esp. the `(.|\s)+?` part?

Comment: Can you provide `$HTML`? Is there an error log when it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

Without a crash log, it's impossible to know exactly whether your expression is the culprit or not. Assuming it is though, it's likely the result of [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) due to greediness.

And not that I advocate for using regular expressions to parse HTML (you'd be better to use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)), but if you continue down the regex path use:

```
$HTML = preg_replace('/<!--([\s\S]+?)-->/','',$HTML);
```

instead. It'll capture both whitespace and non whitespace, including new lines, and won't blow up due to backtracking.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/qR1xW1/1

Answer (score 0):

If the file is particularly large it might be causing the crashes on the other machine. The way that I would've written this is as follows:

```
<!--(.+?)-->
```

There's probably not a particularly decent performance improvement if any at all.

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jG7dZ1/1)

Comment: Don't forget `s` modifier incase comment exceeds one line.

Comment: @chris85 good point, though, i just made an edit that I think is probably a little better for performance and handles newlines :)

Comment: @chris85 i'll probably just keep it with `.` and suggest the s modifier as you had mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
/<!\-\-[\w\s\S]+?\-\->/
```

- `<!` matches the characters `<!` literally
- `\-` matches the character `-` literally
- `\-` matches the character `-` literally
- `[\w\s\S]+?` match a single character present in the list below
- `\w` match any word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- `\s` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`
- `\S` match any non-white space character `[^\r\n\t\f ]`
- `\-` matches the character `-` literally
- `\-` matches the character `-` literally
- `>` matches the characters `>` literally

Comment: What is  I want to find tactic from comment, "<!-- Documents URL $tactic_main_data_root -->"